# Magento2 - Different shipping prices on storeview level

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shipping, shipping-methods

We have a Magento 2 shop with multiple storeviews (Languages).

Let's say shipping to my country costs USD 7, including tax. We have set this up in the backend with the flat rate shipping method.

The price attribute is in the website scope, unfortunately. Is there a way to change the flat rate shipping costs between the different store views?

If not why has someone made this decision to set the shipping methods price to the website scope?

Comment: Magento was built to be extendable so depending on the required changes this might not even be that hard to achieve with your [own module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples). Otherwise, you can try [one](https://marketplace.magento.com/mconnectsolutions-shippingperproductcountries.html) [of](https://www.mconnectmedia.com/flat-rate-shipping-per-country-magento-2.html) [these](https://www.mconnectmedia.com/advance-matrix-rate-shipping-magento-2.html) [modules](https://www.mconnectmedia.com/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-magento2.html).